# KeyError when selecting column after reset_index(drop=True) in Python / Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, keyerror

I'm doing some pivot / melt processes to a df using python / pandas.  First I pivot wide and assign 4 fields as indices:

```
df1_wide = df1_long.pivot(index=id_cols2,columns='Subgroup',values="Students")
```

id_cols2 has the names of the columns I don't want to pivot wide. Then I reset_index() to work on the wide data:

```
df2 = df1_wide.reset_index()
```

I apply a function fn to that (Disc_Type is one of the fields in id_cols2 and 'All Subgroups' is one of the categories that pivoted wide):

```
df2[(df2['Disc_Type'] != 'All_Disc') & (df2['All Subgroups'] < 6)].apply(fn, axis=1)
```

The function works fine.  However, as a next step when I try to melt, it includes the index column in the pivot:

```
df2_long = pd.melt(df2,id_vars=id_cols2,var_name='Subgroup',value_name='Students')
```

So in the "Subgroup" row, it'll have values for "index" and then will list the index number under 'Students'. My first solution was to simply drop the index in the earlier step:

```
df2 = df1_wide.reset_index(drop=True)
```

But then I get a KeyError when I try to reference Disc_Type in the filtering for the function call. I thought reset with drop=True still undoes the existing index/indices, but I guess not?  Any way I should be doing this instead? I'm not sure I'm handing the pivot/melt sequence entirely right.

Comment: please post a reproducible sample of the code along with the error stack trace.

Comment: You seem to be doing it correctly. No need for drop=True in this case. Same sequence of steps works for me on some toy data. So we would need to know what your data looks like and what you are doing in the applied function.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I'll come back with that.  I can't post the actual data, which is confidential, but I'll edit with some dummy data.